# array push creating other elements after adding value to array

Tags: php, arrays

i have a while loop from which im fetching post id and adding them to array like shown below

```
$tobi = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($msql)){
$imp = $result['msg_id'];  // these id are like 316 etc
array_push($tobi, $imp);
}
print_r($tobi);
```

but when i printed the array it resulted

> Array ( [0] => 316 ) Array ( [0] => 315 )

why the array has created another element?
i want the array to be like

```
Array ( [0] => 316 [1] => 315 )
```

i tried using $tobi[] = $imp; also but same result got

after doing print_r($result);

```
Array ( [0] => 318 [msg_id] => 318 ) Array ( [0] => 318 ) Array ( [0] => 317 [msg_id] => 317 ) Array ( [0] => 317 )
```

after doing print_r($msql);

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 2 [type] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 318 ) Array ( [0] => 317 )
```

Comment: `$tobi = array();` Every iteration a fresh array!

Comment: sorry the $tobi = array(); is already out of while loop

Comment: And where is the code line to produce this output?

Comment: @Rizier123 print_r($tobi);

Comment: If you again look at multiple ajax calls, then you have to use the session array to keep the array over new requests

Comment: @Rizier123 it is not a session array

Comment: @SagarSingh can you give us a print_r($result)

Comment: @nerdlyist Array ( [0] => 318 ) Array ( [0] => 317 )

Comment: if you dont' believe i can show you the result page

Comment: @SagarSingh You need a session array if this is over multiple requests.

Comment: @Rizier123 is there any reson why it is creating other element?

Comment: @SagarSingh that is the result you gave for print_r($tobi); I asked for print_r($result)

Comment: Please give the result for var_dump($result)

Comment: Do you have multiple requests here? (AJAX calls)

Comment: yes i have multiple calls@Rizier123

Comment: @nerdlyist check question i have updated

Comment: is it really possible to get multiple arrays returned from `mysqli_fetch_array` as evidenced by your `print_r($result)`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII yeah this is true this is my query $msql = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT msg_id FROM `messages` WHERE time > $last_post_id ORDER BY time DESC");

Comment: @SagarSingh sorry one more do the print_r($msql) outside the while.

Comment: @nerdlyist i received mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 2 [type] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 318 ) Array ( [0] => 317 )

Comment: I know I've already made this comment, but I still don't believe `mysqli_fetch_array` is returning multiple arrays in one call. are you sure you're not omitting/over-simplifying code from your posted example?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII not at all wait i will upload a screenshot with code and result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing too much. Your SQL from the comment

```
$msql = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT msg_id FROM messages WHERE time > $last_post_id ORDER BY time DESC")
```

<strike>is only getting the msg_id so when you call `$imp = $result['msg_id'];` you are creating that. Hence why your Arrays were confusing.</strike>

you should be able to just do:

```
$tobi = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($msql)){

    $tobi[] =  $result[0];
}
print_r($tobi);
```

**UPDATE**

I am not sure why the odd results are being given. It seems that is outputting in ways we cannot see in the code provided. I used my database and ran:

```
$msql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT f_name FROM leads");
```

There are 5 entries 2 do not have f_name. When I did a `print_r($msql)` I received the following:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 5 [type] => 0 )
```

I then ran my code above with both numeric and associative which returned (both ways):

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => TEST [2] => [3] => Coury [4] => 222222 )
```

Also on this set I was able to run the OP original code and get the expected results.

Comment: it resulted in Array ( [0] => 318 ) Array ( [0] => 317 ) Array ( [0] => 318 [1] => 317 )

Comment: by default `mysqli_fetch_array` will return one array with both array indexes, so "you call `$imp = $result['msg_id'];` you are creating that" isn't correct because the associative index should also work

Comment: @JeffPuckettII after using $tobi[] =  $result[0]; i got this Array ( [0] => 318 ) Array ( [0] => 317 ) Array ( [0] => 318 [1] => 317 )

Comment: @SagarSingh, yes I am not surprised this answer doesn't work. I was commenting why it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII does PHP store the associative array elsewhere? Based on the results provided in OP for print_r($msql) it is numeric arrays

Comment: the [return type is optional](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-array-parameters) but on default it will return [`MYSQLI_BOTH`](http://titanic.fauser.edu/php/function.mysqli-fetch-array.php.htm)

Comment: @nerdlyist what should i do now? do i need to edit my query?

Comment: @SagarSingh ones sec I am trying to test this.

Comment: if you think that optional parameter is creating a mess, then try it explicitly `while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($msql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII MYSQLI_ASSOC results in Array ( [0] => 318 ) Array ( [0] => 317 ) Array ( [0] => [1] => )

Comment: @SagarSingh I cannot access my host right now and do not have a local. I would not worry about MYSQLI_ASSOC the numeric seems to be working. I am not sure I understand the output because you are showing multiple arrays. One for each result then the combined one you want.

Comment: @nerdlyist Ok Thanks

Comment: @JeffPuckettIII updated the answer to show you were correct. The way an index is called does not seem to matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this will work!

```
$tobi = array(); $new_arr = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($msql)){
$imp = $result['msg_id'];
$new_arr[] = array_push($tobi, $imp);
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$tobi = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($msql)){
if(isset($result['msg_id']))
 {

$imp = $result['msg_id'];  // these id are like 316 etc
array_push($tobi, $imp);
 }
}
print_r($tobi);
```

Comment: no it does't work please check question i have updated

Answer (score -1):

use this. it may help you.

```
$tobi = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($msql)){
$imp = $result['msg_id'];  
$tobi[]= $imp;
}
print_r($tobi);
```